# img error event not working as expected

Tags: jquery, error-handling

I'm having a bit of an issue with some error handling with jQuery and `<img>` tags. My code looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>welp</title>
</head>
<body>
<a href="http://stackoverflow.com"><img src="www.stackoverflow.com/logo.png" alt="someFakeLink" width="150" height="78"/></a>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("img").on("error", function(){
                $(this).hide();
                alert("AnnoyingPopups");
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm asking because the script works on jsFiddle, but not if I write it in an index.html file.

I'm puzzled and frustrated by this, because it clearly works on jsFiddle, but it doesnt when i do it on my local machine.

Fiddle link is here: https://jsfiddle.net/znq2y6h6/

I hope anyone can explain this to me.

Comment: Do you have any errors in the console of your site?

Comment: Hi, the only error i get in my console is the 404 error from trying to load the image :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to put the image src with 'http', it may help you. So change your image tag like this:

```
    <img src="http://www.stackoverflow.com/logo.png" alt="someFakeLink" width="150" height="78"/>
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch, that appears to have solved it. Can you tell me why it would make a difference?

Comment: Is this the expected answer? The question is to identify if there is any image errors and act accordingly. But the accepted answer looks to correct the error and not provide the solution to identify the error. you can't keep correcting all invalid image sources.

Comment: The answer solves the issue i had, thus i accepted it as an answer?, i dont know what else to say.

I kinda get what you're trying to say. And i could probably wrap the function in something that sees if its a valid URL. But the script is running assuming that the URL is correct, and the imagepath returns a 404 error.

Answer (score 1):

sorry, i make lot of mistake so check with the example

Img error event not working was you have using the document ready function ,so if firstly DOM element will be called then the document ready calling and error event will be bind.

On that time img element already called so that error event not working

**@** In the jsfiddle when they are window.onload function for script and html element

**This code used for you**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>welp</title>
</head>
<body>
<script>
$(document).ready(function()
{
   $("img").on("error", function(){// not working
                $(this).hide();
                alert("AnnoyingPopups");
            });

function imagealertnotworking(e){alert('onerror image alert not working');} // not working
});

function imagealertworking(e){alert('onerror image alert working');} // working
</script>



<a href="http://stackoverflow.com"><img src="www.stackoverflow.com/logo.png" onerror="eval(alert('on dom working alert1'),imagealertworking())"  alt="someFakeLink" width="150" height="78"/></a>
<a href="http://stackoverflow.com"><img src="www.stackoverflow.com/logo.png" onerror="eval(alert('on dom working alert2'),imagealertnotworking())"  alt="someFakeLink" width="150" height="78"/></a>
</body>
</html>
```